# Proof of a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently studying for my Linear Algebra Exam and am struggling with this proof of a Subspace.

*Show that, if U is a non-empty subset of V , then U is a subspace if and only if u − λv ∈ U for all u, v ∈ U and all λ ∈ R.*

I know the three conditions of a Subspace are that the zero vector belongs to U, and that U is closed under both addition and multiplication, but I can't seem to put it into a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Then, for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $u,v\in U$, we have $-\lambda v\in U\implies u-\lambda v\in U$.

Conversely, suppose that $u-\lambda v\in U$ for all $u, v\in U$ and all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $U$ is non-empty, choose $w\in U$. Then, $0=w-w=w-1\cdot w\in U$. Furthermore, if $u, v\in U$, then $u+v=u-(-1)\cdot v\in U$. Moreover, $\lambda v=0-(-\lambda)\cdot v\in U$ since $0\in U$. Thus, $U$ is a subspace.